# Using Boost Filter Iterator with non-Primitive Objects

Tags: c++, boost

Lets say I have a returned iterator from Boost's Multi-Index, where each record contains an age and a name field.

I get the iterator with

```
auto& index = get<age>(m_records);
auto ibegin = index.begin();
auto iend = index.end();
```

How could I use this iterator with Boost's Filter Iterator so that I could return all records that, say have name = "John"?

I set up a struct for the predicate operator, I'm not sure if it's right:

```
struct name_equal_to {
      std::string struct_sname;
      bool operator()(ServerRecord x) { return x.get_name() == struct_sname; }
      name_equal_to(std::string in) : struct_sname(in){}
   };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the filtered adaptor, to make things more readable:

```
for (auto& r : get<age>(m_records) | filtered(name_equal_to("John"))
    std::cout << r << "\n";
```

I'd stylistically improve the functor (**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c12c68b68cd6a35a)**):

```
struct name_equal_to {
    bool operator()(ServerRecord const& x) const { 
        return x.get_name() == sname_; 
    }
    name_equal_to(std::string in) : sname_(std::move(in)){}
  private:
    std::string sname_;
};
```

And to make it really elegant, use Phoenix to define the predicate `named_john` in-place:

```
auto named_john = phx::bind(&record::name, arg1) == "John";
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40c2aeda4700a051)**, where it prints two records ordered by the age index:

```
2 John 40
4 John 57
```

#### Full sample code

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct record {
    int         id;
    std::string name;
    int         age;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const record& e) {
        return os << e.id << " " << e.name << " " << e.age;
    }
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  record,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<tag<struct id>      , BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(record, int        , id)>   ,
    ordered_non_unique<tag<struct name>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(record, std::string, name)> ,
    ordered_non_unique<tag<struct age> , BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(record, int        , age)> >
> employee_set;


employee_set get_records()
{
    employee_set es;

    es.insert(record{ 0,       "Joe",   31 });
    es.insert(record{ 1,    "Robert",   27 });
    es.insert(record{ 2,      "John",   40 });
    // next insertion will fail, as there is an record with the same ID
    es.insert(record{ 2, "Aristotle", 2387 });
    es.insert(record{ 3,    "Albert",   20 });
    es.insert(record{ 4,      "John",   57 });

    return es;
}

#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using namespace phx::arg_names;
using boost::adaptors::filtered;

int main()
{
    auto const m_records = get_records();

    auto named_john = phx::bind(&record::name, arg1) == "John";

    for (auto& r : get<age>(m_records) | filtered(named_john)) {
        std::cout << r << "\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: Awesome, but how does the | in (auto& r : get<age>(m_records) | filtered(named_john)) work?  I don't think I can use a for each in the version of C++ I'm using; that, or the | itself is causing a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

@sehe's answer is absolutely correct, but if you care about efficiency then this is not the fastest way to retrieve all Johns sorted by age. Suppose your container has *N* elements and there are *M* Johns among them. So:

1. Traversing all elements sorted by age and filtering by "John" takes *N* steps.
2. Retrieving all Johns and sorting by age (as discussed in [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868816/find-all-sorted-in-boost)) requires (roughly) 2·log(*N*) steps to retrieve the range of Johns, one allocation of the temporary vector, *M* steps to fill it, O(*M*·log(*M*)) to sort it and *M* to traverse it.

So, it is O(*N*) vs. O(log(*N*)+*M*·log(*M*)). I bet #2 is faster than #1 when *M* << *N*, which I take it to be the usual situation (of course you should measure your actual program).

Comment: Good point I could just use that, I was just curious since I've been trying to learn about Boost.

Comment: This is spot on, I only chose to ignore this issue, as it was _clearly_ not the point of the question.

Comment: @sehe absolutely, just wanted to make sure the OP was aware of the tradeoffs involved. Your proposed code is very elegant, btw.